# how to make a plotly legend span two columns

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am plotting a comparison of lots of data using a plotly graph.
The strings describing each line tend to get long, so I need to make them multiline.
However, with many plots, the legend can run off the screen.
I would like to split the legend into two columns.
Is there a way to do this in plotly? Looking at `help(plotly.graph_objs.Legend)` there is no ncol or similar argument as matplotlib has, and I can't find any reference to this in the plotly documentation.

Here is some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
py.sign_in("XXX", "XXXX")
N = 10
colors=['rgba(%f,%f,%f,%f)' % tuple(c) for c in cm.rainbow((np.linspace(0,1,N)),bytes=True)]
data = []
lab = 'Long<br>Multiline<br>string<br>describing %s'
for i in range(0,N):
    x = np.linspace(0,np.random.uniform(5,10),10)
    y = np.linspace(1,np.random.uniform(0,1),10)
    label = lab % i
    d = Scatter(
        x=x,y=y,
        mode='lines',
        name=label,text=(label,)*len(x),
        xaxis='x1',yaxis='y1',
        line=Line( color=colors[i]) )
    data.append(d)   
py.iplot(data)
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, plotly does not support multi-column legends yet.

One work around would be using annotations. Consider,

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

N = 10
colors=['rgba(%f,%f,%f,%f)' % tuple(c) for c in cm.rainbow((np.linspace(0,1,N)),bytes=True)]

data = []
annotations = []
lab = 'Long<br>Multiline<br>string<br>describing %s'

for i in range(0, N):
    x = np.linspace(0, np.random.uniform(5, 10), 10)
    y = np.linspace(1, np.random.uniform(0, 1), 10)
    label = lab % i

    d = Scatter(
        x=x,y=y,
        mode='lines',
        name=label,text=(label,)*len(x),
        xaxis='x1',yaxis='y1',
        line=Line( color=colors[i]) )
    data.append(d)

    a = Annotation(
        text=label,
        font=Font( color=colors[i] ),
        x=i, y=1,
        xref='page', yref='page'
    )
    annotations.append(a)

layout = Layout(
    showlegend=False,
    annotations=annotations
)

py.plot({'data': data, 'layout': layout}, filename='multi-column-legend')
```

which yields https://plot.ly/~etpinard/2192/

Comment: Is there a way to interact with the annotations so that they turn each plot on/off as the legends do?

Comment: Not at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Are there any news on this front?

Answer (score 4):

Positioning works for me.

```
fig.update_layout(
xaxis_range=['2018-05-30','2020-05-31'],
legend=dict(x=-0.01, y=-0.9),
legend_orientation="h")
```

When I change legend's position by x axis, negative values also effects legend's columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of columns in your legend by typping `entrywidth` and `entrywidthmode`.

More information about these attributes at [Plotly Docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Layout.html#plotly.graph_objects.layout.Legend.entrywidth).

Below you shall see the difference.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
for index in range(6):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[index],
                             y=[index],
                             name=index,
                             mode='markers'))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(entrywidth=0.1, # change it to 0.3
                              entrywidthmode='fraction',
                              orientation='h',
                              y=1.2,
                              xanchor="center",
                              x=0.5))
```

[image: entrywidth=0.1]
[image: entrywidth=0.3]