# in R, creating multi column legend in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, plotly

How do you spread a legend over multiple columns in ggplotly?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400432/creating-multi-column-legend-in-ggplot) makes it obvious how to do so using ggplot() - however that code doesn't seem to work when I use ggplotly()

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) + geom_point(aes(col=row.names(mtcars)))
p
ggplotly(p)
p2<-p + guides(col=guide_legend(ncol=3))
p2 # here we see the legend with 3 column
ggplotly(p2) # here we see the legend with only 1 column
```

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: might not be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189097/how-to-make-a-plotly-legend-span-two-columns